# How to create a dynamic web project in adt-bundle-windows-x86 eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, servlets

I am using adt-bundle-windows-x86 for developing android application.

Now i want to create a dynamic web project so navigate to File->New->other->web under this no option for creating dynamic web project.

I am new to android development... Is there any way to create a servlet file in ADT? or am i install any new software with ADT bundle? if it is which link i add with for installing...

I am creating servlet file in eclipse juno javaEE. Is there any way to access that servlet file in Android application?

Please help me to solve this problem..

Comment: Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> Search for whatever you require -> Hit install. Done.

Comment: Under my Help menu no submenu as Eclipse MarketPlace...@shyam

Comment: Then you'll have to install Eclipse EE and then add ADT plugin from the marketplace